# pandas astype applied to long integer returns a truncated result

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, integer, scientific-notation

wondering if someone came across this issue before
I'm trying to cast a float column in a dataframe to integer , and i'm getting strange results, this is my code :

```
proj_id['test2'] = proj_id['campaign_id'].astype('int64')
proj_id[proj_id['campaign_id']==23847591030830034][['campaign_id','test2']]
```

[image]

so my campaign_id which was
23847591030830034
becomes 23847591030830032

i have tried to suppress scientific expression, rounding, ... but it seems like the conversion truncates a byte off my integer

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it is a matter of representation.

When you do indexing you are casting `23847591030830034` to float which then gets compared with another float that is more accurately represented as `23847591030830032.0` but it is a difference so small that it gets rounded to the same float:

```
>>> floated = float(23847591030830034)
>>> inted = 23847591030830032
>>> floated == float(inted)
True
```

So it seems that the [float representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for both integers is the same hence the discrepancy.

Comment: Thank you Sophros ! do you have any idea how to solve this issue as i need the exact ID for my project purposes

Comment: Store it as `int64` from the beginning?

Comment: I extract the data from a DB using pd.read_sql and it renders the result from the get go in scientific notation float

Comment: The main question is if the column in the DB is of floating-type format (if not you can add the type hint to pandas while reading the data), and another - even if it is float in the database - is it unique? If so, then it does not matter if there are issues of representation. Once you cast the column to `int64` it should be fine.